# Sonar coverage is not calculated

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am trying to integrate my code coverage into the sonar but it shows 0.
I have integrated jacoco as below to my pom but, it still shows the code coverage as zero.

I have only used the pom file from this repository, what other configuration should I work in order to have code coverage ?

What would be other parameters should I possibly add?

https://github.com/daniel-frak/keycloak-user-migration/blob/master/pom.xml

Thanks.

Full repo:

https://github.com/daniel-frak/keycloak-user-migration

Comment: From the logs the sonar "Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer" is not being activated...

Comment: where should I cehck it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that can cause this.

The first thing you should do is examine the workspace to see if the Jacoco plugin wrote its output files anywhere in the "target" tree.  It will generate a data file in one or more formats, but it will also generate an html tree, with an "index.html" in the root.  You can visit that file, and it will show your coverage results.

If you don't find those files, then either your jacoco plugin is not properly integrated with your surefire plugin, or you simply didn't run your unit tests in the build (don't laugh, I've seen people do this).

The "integration" is done by telling Jacoco what variable to put the required command line into, and telling Surefire to use that variable.

Here is a sample jacoco plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${jacoco.path}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note the reference to "surefireArgLine". Here is the Surefire definition that goes with that:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

We also combine this with these property settings:

```
    <jacoco.path>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report</jacoco.path>
    <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${basedir}/target/jacoco_report/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
```

Comment: how can I test it in my locally? in order to check if it creates the jacoco path? And do I need to configure anything on sonarcloud for jacoco ?

Comment: also repository has sonarqube folder , is it for something local test ?

Comment: I assume you're running the sonar scanner on a build server. Just run locally the same build you run on the server.  In the "target" directory, you should have a "jacoco_report" directory. If you don't have that, either your jacoco or surefire plugin is misconfigured.

Comment: Concerning that "sonarqube" folder, I have no clue.

Comment: surefireArgLine can not be resolved, whet should I put here

Comment: I have no idea. You would have to post everything you're doing.